# In programming a game, how can I prevent the script from moving past a click event jQuery assignment?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

New to JS and jQuery - working on a game as an exercise.

I have a "button", to which I assigned an event using jQuery.

That button changes some of the objects on the screen red, and then the user must click the red ones.

When I write the code like this:

```
$("button").click(turnObjectsRed);
if (~someobjects~ are red){
     do xyz
 }
```

The result is the click event is assigned, and then JS evaluates the if statement, which of course is false because I haven't clicked the button yet.

I know I could move all the aspects of the game inside of the click event function, but my goal is to have:

Button -> changes the environment -> things that happen once the environment has changed.

How do I make sure that JS evaluates the the environment AFTER the button has been clicked?

Maybe a while loop that's waiting for a Boolean value to change?

Comment: You would perform the logic inside the `turnObjectsRed` method, or attach another click event listener.  Event listeners are executed in the order they are attached.

Comment: You need to wrap your head around event-driven programming. Everything that happens as a result of the user doing something should be done in the event handler.

Comment: A while loop will not work. Events are not handled until JavaScript returns to the browser's event loop. A while loop will lock up the application, variables will not change. You could do it with `setInterval` that periodically checks a variable, but this is generally frowned upon.

Comment: @Barmar certainly! It's definitely been making much more sense to me as I've done this exercise. I suppose my instincts that this should still be part of the event handling were correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define some function for evaluating the environment, and then call it after you change the color of your objects. This lets you re-evaluate the environment easily in other locations as well.

```
function evaluateEnvironment() {
    if (someObjectsAreRed) {
         // ... Do stuff
    }

    // Do other stuff
}

function turnSomeObjectsRed() {
    // Turn objects red

    evaluateEnvironment();
}

$('button').click(turnSomeObjectsRed);
```

Answer (score 0):

Event handlers are executed in the order they are added.  So you could add another after the one that changes things, if you want to.  Otherwise stick all your logic in the first event handler.

```js
var $test = $('#test');

$test.on('click', function(){
    $test.toggleClass('red blue');
});

$test.on('click', function(){
  if ($test.hasClass('blue')) {
    console.log('you changed me to blue!');
  }
});
```

```css
.red { color: red; }
.blue { color: blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test" class="red">My Text</div>
```